# Como colocar video dentro de uma view

Tags: ios, swift, vídeo

Preciso colocar um video dentro de uma view, nisso ele tem que  rodar só dentro daquele quadrado não em fullscreen.(Tipo facebook)

Eu já pesquisei sobre e só vi tutoriais full screen. Como fazer isso?

Consegui com esse código:

```
class BeginController: UIViewController {
 @IBOutlet weak var videoPreviewLayer: UIView!
 var player: AVPlayer!
 var avpController = AVPlayerViewController!()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let moviePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Hello           Moto", ofType: "mp4")
    if let path = moviePath{
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)
        let item = AVPlayerItem(URL: url)
        self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
        self.avpController = AVPlayerViewController()
        self.avpController.player = self.player
        avpController.view.frame = videoPreviewLayer.frame
        self.addChildViewController(avpController)
        self.view.addSubview(avpController.view)




    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Comment: Bem vinda ao SOpt. O que você já tentou fazer? Adicione na pergunta.

Comment: Obrigada! Já tentei usar o AVPlayer Controller mas tudo que acho na internet só mostra como o video rodar logo que a view carrega. Eu precisava de dar um jeito de colocar o AVPlayer dentro de um subview e ele rodar somente dentro daquela view. Se alguém tiver uma ideia!

Comment: Você precisa da resposta em swift? Ainda precisa de ajuda?

Answer (score 1):

Você irá precisar de Utilizar alguns imports para fazer com melhor perfeição depois veja certinho oque cada um pode fazer por você.

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer
import AVKit
import AVFoundation
```

Agora será necessário criar o componente

```
var videoPlayer: AVPlayerViewController = {
   var view = AVPlayerViewController()
   view.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   return view
}()

let player = AVPlayer()
```

No `viewWillAppear` adicione:

```
self.addChild(videoPlayer)
```

Depois configure as constante de quanto o componente deve ocupar na tela no exemplo abaixo seria uma exibição como a do Youtube:

```
self.view.addSubview(videoPlayer.view)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    self.videoPlayer.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
    self.videoPlayer.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
    self.videoPlayer.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
    self.videoPlayer.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 210)
])

self.videoPlayer.player = player
self.videoPlayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
```

Agora para reproduzir um vídeo basta criar um `AVPlayerItem` com URL externa ou local veja na função abaixo:

```
func reproduzirVideo(item: AVPlayerItem){
    self.videoGravacao.player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: item)
    player.play()
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

estou usando desta forma em Obj-C.

```
#pragma mark - Implementação do Video de Informativo.
// EM - Implementação da View com o Video anunciado.
- (void) informationLoadMovieChanged {

    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"movie" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
    [playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];

    self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    self.player.volume = 0.3;

    AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.player];
    playerLayer.frame = _playerView.bounds;
    playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;
    playerLayer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = YES;


    self.playerView.layer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = YES;
    self.playerView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    self.playerView.layer.borderWidth = 2.5f;
    self.playerView.layer.cornerRadius = 6;
    self.playerView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    [self.playerView.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
    [self.playerView.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
    [self.playerView setPlayer:self.player];
    [self.player play];

    [self.player.currentItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayDidEnd:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:self.player.currentItem];

}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

}

- (void)moviePlayDidEnd:(NSNotification*)notification{

    AVPlayerItem *item = [notification object];
    [item seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
    [self.player play];
}
```

Está rodando dentro de uma view e redimencionada conforme a view.